# Why is the gradient vector orthogonal to the tangent line?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, tangent-line

There is a problem in my book that asks us to use the gradient vector to find the tangent line to a level curve.

I understand that the gradient vector is orthogonal to the level curve - but why does that mean that the gradient vector is also orthogonal to the tangent line?

Comment: The tangent line points in the direction the curve does at each point, therefore the normal at each point is perpendicular to the tangent at each point.

Comment: What could “being orthogonal to a curve” *mean* other than being orthogonal to the curve's tangent line?